# eBay APIs :: Get related categories using title string

Tags: ebay-api

Ok, so this has been asked once before with no answers so i'll give it another bash..

On the eBay website one of the first things you do when listing an item is pass in a string which is the listing title. Given this title string, eBay will go and examine all the categories and pick out a short selection of categories where it thinks you listing will be best suited.

I need to use the bulk File Exchange API and need to find the best category programatically. How can I find the most appropriate categories using one of eBays APIs i.e. is there an API for that?

The only solution I have come up with is to get all the categories using those APIs, then traverse the every category performing some kind of ranking on my inputted listing title (cosine similarity or something).

Any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be able to make use of [GetSuggestedCategories](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSuggestedCategories.html).

From the documentation:

> Specify keywords describing an item you are looking for using the
>   Query input field. GetSuggestedCategories returns a list of up to 10
>   categories that have the highest percentage of listings whose titles
>   or descriptions contains the specified keywords.

Comment: Boom! How did I miss that.. THANK YOU!